# SQL - AND Filter first table by second table's records (Trivial or not?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem which seems trivial but I can't come up with right solution. I did some refactoring of my database so I will explain how the 'games' table was before:

```
ID | Game | show | complexity | environment | preparation (and more attributes)...
```

so one row can look like this:

```
1 | Most Likely To | true | Easy | inside | none
```

So when I had to apply AND filter within attributes (complexity, enviroment..) I did something like:

```
SELECT * FROM games 
WHERE show='true'
```

and now PHP was generating filter by buttons that was clicked, for example if button in group complexity was clicked on 'easy' and 'hard' it added `AND (complexity IN ('easy','hard'))` so it returned only games, that matched this criteria (game could be either 'easy' or 'hard' but not 'very easy')

Because there was so many types of attributes I created one more table and modified the previous one like:

table games : `

```
ID | Game | show
```

table attributes:

```
ID | ID_GAME | attr_type | attribute_value |
```

so previous record would be splitted in two tables like this:

record in table game :

```
1 | Most Likely TO | true
```

records in table attributes:

```
1 | 1 | complexity | Easy
2 | 1 | environment | inside
3 | 1 | preparation | none
```

My question is, how can I create same query that could be generated by PHP like it was before with these tables now?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: While EAV (entity-attribute-value) model enables flexibility in storing attributes, it does come at a price as you are starting to find out!

Comment: Hmm, I think what you rather should have done is to change the attributes (at least some of them, i.e. those using values from a fixed set of possible ones) to be foreign keys to tables that define the possible values, e.g. very easy, easy, hard and very hard for the difficulty. Then you can query these tables instead of the games table to get the values for the buttons. If the attributes aren't mostly variable, there's no need not to model them as columns as you just had it before.